# Paging on collectionView like facebook in swift

Tags: swift, facebook, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell, paging

I am using a collectionView in swift and from webservices I am getting the data(like images and names). If the data is heavy it takes time to load. I want to load the data like only first 10 values and when I reach the bottom of the page next 10 values should appear and similarly next 10 values. But I don't know how to do it.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You basically want something like this: http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/04/27/fastscroll/ or this: http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/